# java.security.cert.CertificateNotYetValidException thrown on newly created java.security.cert.X509Certificate

Tags: java, security

I have a problem i was trying to solve all day, but i just couldn't reconstruct. I have an issue that throws a `CertificateNotYetValidException`  exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateNotYetValidException: certificate not valid till 20130502110036GMT+00:00
```

So, it is not valid until 2013 05 02 11:00.3600
But they tried to verify it, and the next log's time stamp is:
2013-05-02 11:00:34,759
So they tried to verify it .013 seconds before it was valid, but how is that possible? I've written a unit test that did thousands of creating an authentication (that has the certificate) and written the current date immediately, it always rounds down to hundredth of a second, so i could not reproduce the error.

The certificate is generated by bouncycastle certificate generator.

Here is a sample from my jUnit test:

```
 xa = (Authentication) a;
log.info("----current date: " + sdf.format(new Date()));
log.info("not valid before: " + sdf.format(xa.getCertificate().getNotBefore()));
```

And an example output:

```
  INFO  [] ----current date: 2013-05-07 12:03:13.116
  INFO  [] not valid before: 2013-05-07 12:03:12.000

So, if i could of reproduced the issue, i would get something like this:

  INFO  [] ----current date: 2013-05-07 12:03:13.116
  INFO  [] not valid before: 2013-05-07 12:03:14.000

We use java.security.cert.X509Certificate
```

I found a way to reproduce the problem, but this is very far-fetched, I really hope they didn't do this in their tests:

```
xa.getCertificate().checkValidity(new Date(new Date().getTime()-10000));
```

Basically I called checkValidity() on an earlier Date, and this way I get very similar stack trace (not the same, because I used my own unit test).
But I assume they didn't do anything like this... any other idea how i can achieve this error?

Comment: Is the cert generated on the same machine that the test is occurring?

Comment: The cert is generated and there is a verify() called right after it, in the same method, so yes, it is all executed on the same machine. The issue have been pushed aside for now, but I'll post the solution once its figured out.
(Sry for late answer, I didn't notice the small 1 line comment, I'm new here :) )

Comment: Well, the issue have been closed as "Not reproducable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated, it has been closed as "Not reproducible".

It is a pretty strange error... We have no idea how they made this exception to be thrown. They didn't call checkValidity() on earlier dates, only used dates provided by system. I guess it's one of those mystery Java errors :) So far no mention have came of another error like this, and it's been month since we closed the issue.

Anyway, I just wanted to answer this question so it doesn't show up as unanswered. I hope it's not a problem.

Comment: Which time zone were you in? The cert time should be UTC times.